# Some pointer questions

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Is array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

I was running the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
  int (*b)[4] = &a;
  int k = sizeof(a);
  printf("\n\n%d\n\n", k);
  printf("a = %u, b = %u, *b = %u, data = %d", a, b, *b, **b);
  return 0;
}
```

I got the following output

```
a = 3485401628, b = 3485401628, *b = 3485401628, data = 1
```

Here I am assigning the address of a to b, as the type of b is int**, but in the output I am getting that the address pointed by the a is the same as the address pointed by b.

It seems little confusing to me. What is the explanation?

Comment: Wouldn't the address of something be the result of applying the _address-of operator_? i.e., `&a`

Comment: 32 or 64 bit machine? i suspect 64

Comment: On your last question about the subject, Carl suggested that you'd read up on pointers before asking here. Did you do that? I can't believe that you didn't find anything valuable that could help you on this. http://www.c-faq.com/ is a good starting point. Also please learn how to come up with a more precise question title. This would already be a good step for yourself to learn what your problem is.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the accepted answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/771663)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of array `a` is the pointer to the first element of the array `a`.

The value of pointer `&a` (which is the same value and type as pointer `b`) is the pointer to the array `a`.

They have the same value (but different types) as they both start at the same memory address. There is no padding possible at the beginning of an array.

When evaluated `a` is of type `int *` and `&a` is of type `int (*)[4]`.

Note that the correct way to print the address of a pointer is to use conversion specifier `p`. E.g.,

```
/* And p requires the argument to be a void *, so use a cast if
 * it is not the case
 */
printf("%p %p\n", (void *) a, (void *) &a);
```

Comment: thank you ouah , for giving such a nice explanation......

Answer (score 0):

On expressions (such as an argument for printf) arrays are decayed to pointers (to their respective arrays), meaning that if "b" points to "a", on an expression, "a" will also be a pointer to "a" (the block of memory allocated for "a").

The way of accessing elements at runtime however (internally), is different. In this case, "b" would require an additional indirection.